# Recieve data twice over Python TCP Socket

Tags: python, sockets, tcp

I'm trying to use a python script that sends and receives data from a server.
First, the client receives a welcome message and is asked for input from the server. The client should then should send the prepared response and when that is finished save the servers response. It boils down (client side) to Receive, Send, Receive.

The function I've written is this:

```
s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s.connect((TCP_IP, TCP_PORT))
data = s.recv(BUFFER_SIZE)
s.send(MESSAGE)
data2 = s.recv(BUFFER_SIZE)
s.close()
print "received data:", data
print "received data2:", data2
```

Yet when the program runs I only get a response from data, not data2.

Is there a way to get it to receive, send, and then receive again?

EDIT: Server Code-

```
self.request.send("What is your name? ")
data = self.request.recv(4096).strip('\n')
self.request.send('Welcome' + data)
self.request.close()
```

The server code works just fine in netcat, I'm just trying to interact with it in python now

---

### UPDATE: Solution

```
s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s.connect((TCP_IP, TCP_PORT))
s.send(MESSAGE)
data = s.recv(BUFFER_SIZE)
data2 = s.recv(BUFFER_SIZE)
s.close()
print "received data:", data
print "received data:", data2
```

Comment: It's not possible to determine what the problem is without seeing the code for *both* sides of the connection.

Comment: Probably it's your server-side for some reason did not send data after received 'prepared response' from client.

Comment: I can make a guess: What does `s.send(MESSAGE)` return? Is it less than `len(MESSAGE)`? Is the server waiting for a whole `len(MESSAGE)` bytes before it will send a response? More generally, (TCP) [sockets are byte streams, not message streams](http://stupidpythonideas.blogspot.com/2013/05/sockets-are-byte-streams-not-message.html), and your code seems to be built around an invalid assumption.

Comment: One more thing: what does "I only get a response from data, not data2" mean? Doe sit block forever in that `data2 =` line? Or return 0 bytes? Or raise an exception? or something different?

Comment: I updated the question to include the server code. And by "only get a response from data, not data2" I mean that the print line for data2 shows nothing, while the print line for data1 shows the welcome message.

Comment: Try adding `self.request.shutdown(socket.SHUT_RDWR)` right before closing.

Comment: The server works for everything else, just not this python script. I would edit the server more but I don't have access to edit it. Is there anyway I could do this in python client side?

Comment: That server code is wrong in at least two ways. I'm surprised it works for you at all.

Comment: Your suggested solution is completely wrong, too. TCP is a stream oriented protocol, not message oriented (as already mentioned in previous comments). Calling `s.recv()` twice in a row will *not* give you the results you really want. The fact that it works for you is only an accident. You might get both results in `data`, or a partial result in `data` and the rest in `data2`, or one byte in `data` and another byte in `data2`, or any other combination. TCP only guarantees that the bytes you read are the same bytes in the same order that were sent, and nothing about message boundaries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

data2 didn't print anything because you only called .send() once... There is nothing left in the buffer to send or receive by the time we have the second .recv() call.

Comment: Ahh that worked! I'll write the code that worked in my question for future googlers. Thank you!!!